# Hot deployment in wildfly-9.0.1.Final throws error

Tags: java, spring, jboss, wildfly

I am using wildfly-9.0.1.Final for my app(spring, hibernate) deployment.

The app deploys fine if I place it in the desired folder and then start the app server. However, if I try to do hot deployment, then I am often getting the following error

```
2015-09-18 11:27:11,710 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC
service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = abc.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
2015-09-18 11:27:12,901 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 91) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.11-jbossorg-1 20150505-1501 for context '/abc'
2015-09-18 11:27:12,933 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 91) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: G:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\tempcca6b82fbbb1b290\content-9caf3814215c1a2e\content-3791740010714739653.tmp (Access is denied)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:764)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:353)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: G:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\tempcca6b82fbbb1b290\content-9caf3814215c1a2e\content-3791740010714739653.tmp (Access is denied)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:751)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: G:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\tempcca6b82fbbb1b290\content-9caf3814215c1a2e\content-3791740010714739653.tmp (Access is denied)
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.getResources(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1360)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1329)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:742)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: G:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\tempcca6b82fbbb1b290\content-9caf3814215c1a2e\content-3791740010714739653.tmp (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.RealFileSystem$1.run(RealFileSystem.java:111)
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.RealFileSystem$1.run(RealFileSystem.java:109)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.RealFileSystem.doIoPrivileged(RealFileSystem.java:91)
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.RealFileSystem.openInputStream(RealFileSystem.java:109)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.openStream(VirtualFile.java:254)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualJarInputStream.openCurrent(VirtualJarInputStream.java:223)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualJarInputStream.getNextJarEntry(VirtualJarInputStream.java:109)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualJarInputStream.getNextJarEntry(VirtualJarInputStream.java:96)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualJarInputStream.getNextEntry(VirtualJarInputStream.java:80)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.Classpath.searchFromURL(Classpath.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.Classpath.searchFromURL(Classpath.java:242)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.Classpath.search(Classpath.java:156)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.Classpath.search(Classpath.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.loadURLs(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.getResources(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:110)
    ... 16 more
```

What can I do to avoid this error and ensure the hot deployment goes fine?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Every error is a permission denied error.  Which O/S user runs the Wildfly process and who are the owners of the directories under G:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp?  I'd guess that there is an O/S owner problem.

Comment: I have already tried giving my current user full permission to that folder but still it fails

Answer (score 0):

Please check another stackoverflow post:
[Wildfly fails to deploy application (FileNotFoundException - Access is Denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154261/wildfly-fails-to-deploy-application-filenotfoundexception-access-is-denied/)

You have to remove these lines from your configuration (standalone.xml):

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
```

And

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
```