# Wildfly deploy failed: JBAS014671 and WFLYCTL0080 - Access is denied

Tags: java, windows, jakarta-ee, wildfly

We have deployed a WAR file to Wildfly using the Deployment Scanner ("deployments" folders). The web app works until the computer is rebooted - it fails when the web app is loaded by the server again. It's worth saying that we don't have this problem if the Wildfly service is restarted, it happens only when the whole OS is restarted. And if I just restart Wildfly, it works back again.

If I delete the failed file flag (healthsafety-server.war.failed) from the deployments folder, the application is successfully deployed after few seconds.

If the deploy is being done through the Administrator console, it fails the first time. However, if the app is disabled and then enabled back again, it works too.

We're running Wildfly 8.2.0 Final on Windows 10 Home (64bits English), but we tried Wildfly 9.0.2 Final too and we got the same behavior. We had the same problem on a different computer with Windows 8.1 64 bits Professional.

The Wildfly folder is placed on the "C:\" folder and full control has been provided to all users, including "everyone". [These steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cn-dgqoeh9I) were also applied but the issue persists.

This is the content from the **healthsafety-server.war.failed** file on **Wildfly 8.2.0 Final**:

```
"{\"JBAS014671: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./healthsafety-server\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./healthsafety-server: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\tempea4e3edc0321f2c2\\\\healthsafety-server.war-4135c52d8f677a8a\\\\healthsafety-server.war-7794207299642458131.tmp (Access is denied)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\tempea4e3edc0321f2c2\\\\healthsafety-server.war-4135c52d8f677a8a\\\\healthsafety-server.war-7794207299642458131.tmp (Access is denied)
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\tempea4e3edc0321f2c2\\\\healthsafety-server.war-4135c52d8f677a8a\\\\healthsafety-server.war-7794207299642458131.tmp (Access is denied)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\tempea4e3edc0321f2c2\\\\healthsafety-server.war-4135c52d8f677a8a\\\\healthsafety-server.war-7794207299642458131.tmp (Access is denied)
    Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\tempea4e3edc0321f2c2\\\\healthsafety-server.war-4135c52d8f677a8a\\\\healthsafety-server.war-7794207299642458131.tmp (Access is denied)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\tempea4e3edc0321f2c2\\\\healthsafety-server.war-4135c52d8f677a8a\\\\healthsafety-server.war-7794207299642458131.tmp (Access is denied)\"}}"
```

and this is the content from the **healthsafety-server.war.failed** file on **Wildfly 9.0.2 Final**:

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./healthsafety-server\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./healthsafety-server: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\temp2bdea2bc34b5d6c1\\\\content-ed5f82fbe5807374\\\\content-4117938517180519169.tmp (Access is denied)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\temp2bdea2bc34b5d6c1\\\\content-ed5f82fbe5807374\\\\content-4117938517180519169.tmp (Access is denied)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\temp2bdea2bc34b5d6c1\\\\content-ed5f82fbe5807374\\\\content-4117938517180519169.tmp (Access is denied)
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\temp2bdea2bc34b5d6c1\\\\content-ed5f82fbe5807374\\\\content-4117938517180519169.tmp (Access is denied)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\temp2bdea2bc34b5d6c1\\\\content-ed5f82fbe5807374\\\\content-4117938517180519169.tmp (Access is denied)
    Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\temp2bdea2bc34b5d6c1\\\\content-ed5f82fbe5807374\\\\content-4117938517180519169.tmp (Access is denied)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\\\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\\\\standalone\\\\tmp\\\\vfs\\\\temp\\\\temp2bdea2bc34b5d6c1\\\\content-ed5f82fbe5807374\\\\content-4117938517180519169.tmp (Access is denied)\"}}"
```

Any help is appreciated.

PS: [cross-post on JBoss forums](https://developer.jboss.org/message/948830#948830)

Comment: Do you have a WildFly instance in your IDE? I found that this caused many problems for me of a similar nature to what you are experiencing(problems with content below ${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/ ).

 I would recommend removing the server from your workspace and replacing your ${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone directory with a fresh one.(Just download it again). Then avoid starting your server from your IDE...only use the command line.

Comment: Hi @DuranWesleyHarris, we're using the WildFly outside the IDE, always running as a (Windows) service or the command line as you mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the tmp folder? I would try that first

Are you deploying exploded or unexploded archives? Just something to try but maybe try changing the deployment scanner to automatically deploy? (No need to add the .doDeploy marker...)

Comment: Yes, we tried to delete the folder but didn't solve. We're using only unexploded archives (war file), and tried to deploy in both ways: with and without the .dodeploy marker; and in both cases the server is generating the .failed marker.

Comment: Have you inspected the javax.faces modules in standalone? Did you not recently change anything in the faces module? Check the xml file in the module and the permissions on the jars that it references.  It's weird that it says it is a FacesConfigurationException and that it is failing to access something in the war. Maybe it is set to JSF 1.2 but there is no faces-config.xml? Apart from that I'm at a loss

Comment: Hey @DuranWesleyHarris, thanks for the answer. We're currently working in a different project and I couldn't check this yet.. As soon as we return to that project I'll check this and update here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After upgrading from win7 to win10 I had the same issue. Issue seems to be caused by Windows Defender real-time protection. Solution was to exclude the {wildfly folder}\standalone\tmp\vfs folder in Defender. Hope it'll work for you, too.

Answer (score -1):

Please check another stackoverflow post: [Wildfly fails to deploy application (FileNotFoundException - Access is Denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154261/wildfly-fails-to-deploy-application-filenotfoundexception-access-is-denied/)

You have to remove these lines from your configuration (standalone.xml):

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
```

And

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
```

Comment: What happens if you actually need JSF? removing them is not an option, just like turning off you antivirus software.